# scanf usando punteros a cadena dentro de estructuras

Tags: c

estoy realizando un programa en C, en donde hay un arreglo dinámico de estructuras, pero al imprimir los datos del arreglo, la ejecución se rompe y no imprime más que un sólo elemento de la estructura. Para fines prácticos, sólo genero un arreglo con un elemento.

**Función principal**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct 
    {
        int id;
        char *nombre_producto;
        char *departamento;
        float precio;
    } PRODUCTO;
    
    void insertarDatos(PRODUCTO *p, int size);
    void imprimirDatos(const PRODUCTO *p, int size);
    
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        // reserva de memoria para el arreglo de productos.
        PRODUCTO *productos = NULL;
        int size = 1;
    
        productos = (PRODUCTO *) malloc(size * sizeof(PRODUCTO));
        
        insertarDatos(productos, size);
    
        imprimirDatos(productos, size);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

**Funciones para leer datos e imprimir**

```
void insertarDatos(PRODUCTO *p, int size) 
{
    printf("\n\n***** Intertar datos ******\n\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Id: "); scanf("%i", &(p + i)->id);
        printf("\nNombre del producto: "); scanf("%s", &(p + i)->nombre_producto);
        printf("\nDepartammento: "); scanf("%s", &(p + i)->departamento);
        printf("\nPrecio: "); scanf("%s", &(p + i)->precio);
    }
    
}

void imprimirDatos(const PRODUCTO *p, int size) 
{
    printf("\n\n*****Datos Del Arreglo*****\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Id: %i\n", (p + i)->id);
        printf("Nombre: %s\n", (p + i)->nombre_producto);
        printf("Departamento: %s\n", (p + i)->departamento);
        printf("Precio: %0.2f\n", (p + i)->precio);
    }  
}
```

**Fallo al compilar**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la imagen que muestras, parece que los resultados no son los que esperas ... ¡ lo raro es que no recibas directamente un error de acceso a memoria !

En tu estructura

```
typedef struct {
  int id;
  char *nombre_producto;
  char *departamento;
  float precio;
} PRODUCTO;
```

declaras 2 miembros como punteros a cadena ... ¡ pero **nunca reservas espacio** para esas cadenas, ni **nunca inicializas** esos punteros !

```
void insertarDatos( PRODUCTO *p, int size ) {
  printf( "\n\n***** Intertar datos ******\n\n" );

  for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    /*
      AQUÍ
      Reservamos e inicializamos los punteros a cadena.
    */
    p[i].nombre_producto = (char *)calloc( sizeof( char ), 50 );
    p[i].departamento = (char *)calloc( sizeof( char ), 50 );

    printf( "Id: " ); scanf( "%i", &( p[i].id ) );
    printf( "\nNombre del producto: " ); scanf( "%s", p[i].nombre_producto );
    printf( "\nDepartammento: " ); scanf("%s", p[i].departamento );
    printf( "\nPrecio: " ); scanf( "%f", &(p[i].precio ) );
  }
}
```

Adicionalmente, para obtener un `float` mediante `scanf( )`, se usa el indicador `%f` (tenías puesto `%s`).

Observa que reservamos espacio para 50 caracteres (49 + el `0` final). Deberías cambiar ese tamaño si lo necesitas, u obtener las cadenas de otra manera.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda, sí lo del %s, se me fue, no lo vi. Una duda, para reservar memoria en los punteros a cadenas, ¿por qué reservas memoria en cada iteración del for?.

Comment: Hay que reservar memoria para cada elemento de `productos`, **no** lo puedes hacer para todos a la vez.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, de echo lo intente reservar memoria una sola vez y sí funciona, pero no del todo bien, ya que cuando acaba de imprimir todo (de manera correcta) se queda colgado la consola como cinco segundos y termina la ejecución. En fin gracias por ayudarme a ver mis errores, saludos.

Comment: Otra cosa amigo, abusando de tu ayuda, sabes de alguna biblioteca o framework para hacer pruebas unitarias en c, eso de estar creando código desde cero para pruebas no es muy eficiente jejejeje

Comment: `673.000` resultados: https://www.google.com/search?q=unit+test+c&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8